# Bootstrap 3 dropdown nav not staying focused

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, focus, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav

I have a Bootstrap navigation:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"> 
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png"></a> </div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Neuigkeiten <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Galerie</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
    <li><a href="#">Fahrzeuge</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Ausbildung <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Allgemein</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Versehrten</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Fremdsprachig</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ferien</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Seminare</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">LKW</a></li>  
  </ul>
  <!--<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>--> 
</div>
<!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

and made a few hover effects (I change the background-color). Now I want the dropdown menu to appear also on hover. So I added this:

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu{
display: block;
margin-top:-1px;
}
```

But now if the mouse leaves the main menu item in order to click something in the now opened dropdown menu, it has no longer the changed background-color... (because it is no longer focused?!?)

But what do I have to do so that the main menu item stays focused (keeps the hover background color) even if the mouse is navigating through the corresponding dropdown menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the drop down is being hovered you need to modify the `.dropdown-toggle` as well. Add the following `CSS`.

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover .dropdown-toggle {
   color: #555;
   background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to use jQuery like this :

```
$('.navbar-toggle').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
        $(this).blur();
    };
});
```